# Can "Virtually" and "practically" be adjectives?

Tags: grammar, meaning

According to the passage:

> "Deserts, arid areas with virtually no vegetation, cover more than one-third of the land of earth"

(there’s no verb between with virtually no vegetation)

Comment: Virtually and practically (adverbs), meaning "almost", need no verb following.

Comment: *Virtually* is an adverb modifying *no*.

Answer (score 1):

> An adverb is a word or set of words that modifies verbs, adjectives,
>   or other adverbs. Adverbs answer how, when, where, why, or to what
>   extent—how often or how much (e.g., daily, completely).

In this case, both are adverbs. Adverbs can be used to modify an adverb as well.

Example:

> He speaks very slowly